# How to add additional top-level navigation category and subpages in TextPattern CMS?

Tags: textpattern

I am new to TextPattern CMS.

How can I add additional top-level navigation categories and subpages to our current TextPattern-based CMS and website?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a combination of Categories and Sections.

According to their [site](http://textpattern.com/faq):

> Categories can be used independently (to list articles from all sections in the National category, for example), or combined with sections (to list articles in section Politics with category World).
>
> ---
>
> Sections are usually the topmost navigation elements of your web site. If you want a simple, automatic list of links to sections, use the section_list tag:
>
> ```
> <txp:section_list wraptag="ul" break="li" />
> ```
>
> This puts the links in an unordered list, so you can use CSS to alter the layout as required.
>
> For a popup selection list, use the popup tag:
>
> ```
> <txp:popup type="s" />
> ```
>
> If you want more control over the content of the list (to omit certain sections, or use a specific order), the best way is with the `<txp:section />` tag (requires Textpattern 4.0.2+):
>
> ```
> <ul>
> <txp:section wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="about" />
> <txp:section wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="articles" />
> <txp:section wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="news" />
> <txp:section wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="contact" />
> </ul>
> ```
>
> If you’ve created static pages, like an about or contact page, you can link to them by linking to the associated section:
>
> ```
> <txp:section link=1 title=1 name="about" />
> <txp:section link=1 title=1 name="contact" />
> ```
>
> Category links are specified in a similar way. There’s a category_list tag:
>
> ```
> <txp:category_list wraptag="ul" break="li" />
> ```
>
> The popup tag can also be used for categories:
>
> ```
> <txp:popup type="c" />
> ```
>
> Please note however that categories are independent of sections. Both of these tags will link to a list of articles in all sections that belong to the selected category.
>
> For more control, you can use the category tag (also requires Textpattern 4.0.2+):
>
> ```
> <ul>
> <txp:category wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="products" />
> <txp:category wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="weather" />
> <txp:category wraptag="li" link=1 title=1 name="photos" />
> </ul>
> ```